# Stream closed Hibernate persistence

Tags: java, hibernate, openjpa

Recently i am getting stream closed issue during download the submitted orders. This is a working code and all of sudden it is happened and got the below error.
application is connecting by multiple users and i feel that this may be due to connection.please correct me.

The code below where the error occurs shows in the log.This is not full code.
Why I am getting stream closed and I am using HibernatePersistence in the Persistence.xml

```
parseOrders(header, xmlReader, OrderNumbers, placeNumbers);
        int size = 0;
        int index = 0;

        try {
            if(OrderNumbers.size()>0 || placeNumbers.size()>0) {
                orderRemote orderRemote = getService();
                List<String> tmpReqNumbers = null;
                orLst = new ArrayList<Order>(); 

 try {
            if(OrderNumbers.size()>0 || placeNumbers.size()>0) {
                orderRemote orderRemote = getService();
                List<String> tmpReqNumbers = null;
                orLst = new ArrayList<Order>();
 //free the resources
                OrderNumbers.clear();
                OrderNumbers = null;
            }



            writeRsp(header, xmlOutput, woLst);
            //clean the stateful order resource.
            woRemote.closeSession();  Here is the place it shows error

         logs shows as below:
                Clean up user entity manager factory now...
               Number of user factory clean up 0
                java.lang.NullPointerException
                at 



org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.readExternal(EntityManagerImpl.java:1246)

code: 2; severity: -1; cause: Stream closed; vars: 0 - Closed Response, 1 - Stream closed; msg: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Stream closed

Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Stream closed
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1692)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.writeEndDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:585)
    at com.ctc.wstx.evt.WstxEventWriter.add(WstxEventWriter.java:97)
    at xmlMarshaller.java:117)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.ensureOpen(StreamEncoder.java:26)
```

This code is deployed in Jboss and I feel that multiple users trying simultaneously
due that stream closed happened. Not sure correct me.

Thanks in Advance